# WinUI integration with COM / WinForm / WPF controls

Tags: c#, wpf, com, activex, winui

I was wondering if there is any way to embed ActiveX components (created as a WPF / Winforms Control) into WinUI. I have the opportunity build an app from scratch and there is just one critical functionality that has this dependency.
I created a winui 3.0 project but I cannot seem to include my WPF / OCX control

Comment: I've asked Microsoft, but they don't care (or they don't really understand how it's important for smooth migration scenarios): https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4670